# LJ Dynamic Fields - Only Seeing Latest 100 entries

Tags: drop-down

I am currently creating various component entries (under channels). Once created I can then add that specific component to structure (know on my site as a work page).

On the work page I have a dynamic field (see https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-dynamic-fields) that allows a user to scroll through these already created component entries in a dropdown list style. That drop down is a dynamic dropdown generated through LJ dynamic fields with the following code in the CMS.

```
{% include '_dynamicfields/sections' ignore missing %}
```

From there the included file is as follows...

```
{% for channel in craft.entries.section('components') %}
   { "value":"{{ channel.id }}" , "label":"{{ channel | raw }}" }
   {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately as of late I'm only seeing the latest 100 entries. I haven't seen any reference in either craft CMS documentation or the LJ Dynamic fields documentation.

Comment: Is this Craft 2 or 3? I would have guessed Craft 2, but you linked to the Craft 3 repo for the plugin.

Comment: Craft 2 - trying to update with the appropriate versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Craft 2 will only return 100 elements (entries, assets, users, etc.) at a time.

If you want to get more than that, you need to use `limit(null)`.

```
{% for channel in craft.entries.section('components').limit(null) %}
```

This behavior changed in Craft 3 so there is no default limit.